# How to check if knockout has finished data binding

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am currently trying to implement the panelBar feature from KendoUI into an app at work. I have realized that kendoUI and KnockOut do not interact very well together. The main problem at the moment is the implementation of the panelBar is not working very well due to having a dynamic knockout property disrupting it. Here is the ko that I have found to interfere:

data-bind="foreach: filters

This little code is inside a div wrapping others. But the main problem is the foreach is interfering with KendoUI. I figure the way to fix this is by having some way of checking if knockout is finished all the binding, and THEN calling the code to implement kendoUI.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think `ko.applyBindings()` is an async call. After that line in your script, binding should be done.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: the problem is that the kendoUI panelbar is not being implemented, because of the data-binding - so i am trying to work around that right now

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Knockout binding handlers for Kendo UI? If not, check out these binding handlers. In short, they help work out the interfaces between the two libraries. http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/